# I would like to have a pointer on regex for my php code

Tags: php, regex

```
if (preg_match('/^[0-9{2}-?){6}][A-Za-z][0-9{2}]/', $_POST['Client_id']) == 0) {
        exit(' Your ID is not valid!');
    }
```

Iam trying to validate Client_id, the above code preg_match must suit such an example 08-786596 H 12 i have been trying to validate, i keep getting an error that ID is not valid Your assistance will be greatly appreciated..

Comment: If you need help on regex basics, https://regex101.com is a good site to test & get explanations of what specific parts of a pattern do. Your current attempt appears not even syntactically valid, it gives a pattern error for `[0-9{2}-` already, “Character range is out of order”.

Comment: The braces are mixed up in the first part. Just look closely

Comment: You probably want something more like this, `^[0-9]{2}-[0-9]{6} [A-Za-z] [0-9]{2}$` – https://regex101.com/r/XZwZhH/1

Comment: Try something like:
/^[0-9]{2}\-[0-9]{6}\s[A-Z]\s[0-9]{2}/